# LabVIEW LED matrix text board

Tags: vi, labview

I am making a LabVIEW VI for simulating the signs that are above the highways in some countries. I already have the boards for each lane and the LED's that indicate the maximum speed or if a lane is closed or open.

Under these signs I want to place a textboard where a text message can be displayed, for example a message that a traffic jam is coming up.

The problem is that I have totally no clue HOW to make this. I want the textboard to consists out of LED's to show the message on the board, so there needs to be some converting text to LED's.

Do you know how to convert text to LED's on a LED matrix so that they light up in the correct way so that it will display the message? Please help me out on this :)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already wrote an string to scrolling LED display in LabVIEW. You would just need to take the Boolean signals that I've got and instead of routing them to the UI, route them to your hardware. See here: https://decibel.ni.com/content/docs/DOC-1180

Comment: Wow Srm thanks! This looks very close to what I need :) I am not a LabView Pro so I'm a bit confused by the number of different labview files to run this project. I dont need the LED display to scroll, I need it to be static. Can you please tell me more about what files I need to modify from your project please?

Comment: You may only need the core functionality... I built this into a full XControl -- usable as the front panel. :-)

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is convert text into a [bitmap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitmap) array where each bit indicates whether a particular LED is lit up or not.

This process is common in rendering text to any [raster graphics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raster_graphics) display.

After the bitmap is set up, then all that needs to be done is output it to the LED drivers.  Depending on the interface, it is either by sending all the bits out into [shift registers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_register), or doing some kind of addressing.